# Essentially bounded function which is continuously bounded Riemann integrable?

Tags: analysis

Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability states:

> A bounded function on a compact interval [a, b] is Riemann integrable if and only if it is continuous almost everywhere.

Can we change bounded to "essentially bounded", that means bounded except for a set of measure zero, and still have Riemann integrability?